# Append to character found in string

Tags: php, regex

How can I in php, append a character to another character within! a string, with perhaps regex.

If I have an array, lets say:

```
$array=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
$long_string="yada yada yada yada yada....";
```

If I wanted to append an exclamation mark to each of the characters in $array, found in $long_string how would that be done with regex? At the moment my skills only give me the option to do a loop over the string, and I understand that is not the smoothest way to do it.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) that may take an array of search and replace values. The replacement value array can be easily built from the search char array using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Zx82ep):

```
$array=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
$repl = array_map(function ($i) { return $i."!"; }, $array);
$long_string="yada yada yada yada yada....";
echo str_replace($array, $repl, $long_string);
// => ya!d!a! ya!d!a! ya!d!a! ya!d!a! ya!d!a!....
```

A regex approach (if the search items are single alpha characters):

```
$array=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
$long_string="yada yada yada yada yada....";
$rx = "[" . implode("", $array) . "]";
echo preg_replace('/'.$rx.'/', '$0!', $long_string);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2dhrK3). The regex will be `/[abcdefghij]/` (a character class that matches a single char) and the replacement contains the backreference to the whole match (`$0`) and the `!` symbol added to each match.

If your search items are multiple char strings and can contain non-word chars, it  is safer to use an alternation group and preg_quote the items ([demo](https://ideone.com/x7iPrQ)):

```
$rx = "(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function($i) {return preg_quote($i, "/");}, $array)) . ")";
echo preg_replace('/'.$rx.'/', '$0!', $long_string);
```

The regex will look like `(?:a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j)` then.

All regexps can be tested at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Comment: Thank you for this Wiktor. What about if the characters are say any of these: . ; / \ ( )

Comment: The last solution will work. Though for single chars you can combine the last with the first. `$rx = "[" . implode("", array_map(function($i) {return preg_quote($i, "/");}, $array)) . "]";`

Comment: Thank you, just heading home now and will try it right when i get in.

Answer (score 0):

Its not regex but you can have a simple solution without having to loop through string:

```
$array=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
$long_string="yada yada yada yada yada....";
$array_string = str_split($long_string);
$unique = array_unique($array_string);

foreach($array as &$a){
  if(in_array($a,$unique)){
    $a = $a.'!';
  }
}

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "a!"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "d!"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "f"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "g"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "h"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "i"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "j"
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i dont want to use a for loop. the long string might be a blog post, or a comment.